# Extend a Widget called from another file

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Good evening everyone, in practice I created a file containing some functions that are based on firestore that I have to reuse in other files, this is the code:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cron/cron.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:goodgoals_android/services/authentication.dart';

abstract class Service {
  Future<void> NumberGenerator();

  Future<void> MissionRetriever1();

  Future<void> MissionRetriever2();

  Future<void> MissionRetriever3();

  Future<void> MissionRetriever4();

}

class MissionService implements Service {
  MissionService({this.auth});
  int missionNumber1;
  int missionNumber2;
  int missionNumber3;
  int missionNumber4;
  int test = 10;
  final BaseAuth auth;
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final databaseReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance;



  Future<void> NumberGenerator() {
    final cron= Cron();
    cron.schedule(Schedule.parse('*0**1'), () async { //Tutti i Lunedì alle 00;
    Random random = new Random();
    missionNumber1 = random.nextInt(10);
    missionNumber2 = random.nextInt(10);
    missionNumber3 = random.nextInt(10);
    missionNumber4 = random.nextInt(10);
  });
  }


  Future<void> MissionRetriever1() async{
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("quest")
        .doc("1")
        .get();
    }

  Future<void> MissionRetriever2() async{
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("quest")
        .doc(missionNumber2.toString())
        .get();
  }

  Future<void> MissionRetriever3() async{
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("quest")
        .doc(missionNumber3.toString())
        .get();
  }

  Future<void> MissionRetriever4() async{
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("quest")
        .doc(missionNumber4.toString())
        .get();
  }




  }
```

In practice I would need to call the MissionRetriever1 function in another file, and then save the values ​​with **then** like this :

```
  Future<void> getMission1() async{
    return await widget.mservice.MissionRetriever2
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        print("Done");
        setState(() {
          MissionData1.add(doc["Name"]);
        });
      }),
    });
  }
```

But doing so gives me the error: The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'Function'.

Any advise?

Comment: You can't ```await``` and use ```then``` in the same combination. You either ```await``` and assign the value, or use ```then``` and get a callback when the future emits the event.

Comment: I have already tried to remove the await in the function with .then but the error remains

Comment: It should be ```widget.mservice.MissionRetriever2()``` becuase that's a function call not an instance member. Also a friendly suggestion check out the naming conventions for dart, they will make your code more readable.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice to increase readability, for the problem  if I add the () when I call the widget I get this new error : The argument type 'Set<void> Function(QuerySnapshot)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<void> Function(void)'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing the () after MissionRetriever2. Your IDE likely didn't warn you because you had everything uppercase which is standard for class names, but not functions. Functions should follow camelcase ex: missionRetriever2

```
Future<void> getMission1() async{
    return await widget.mservice.MissionRetriever2()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        print("Done");
        setState(() {
          MissionData1.add(doc["Name"]);
        });
      }),
    });
    }
```

Note you also don't need to combine the usage of await & .then() callbacks a cleaner way to do this would be:

```
Future<void> getMission1() async{
    var snap = await widget.mService.missionRetriever2();
    for(var doc in snap.docs){
        missionData1.add(doc.data()['Name']);
    }
}
```